# 404 Error when trying to send param through anchor tag to servlet

Tags: html, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am attempting to send a parameter through my anchor tag on my jsp to one of my servlets. In doing so I receive a 404 error. I have given the exact syntax of how I wrote my anchor tag. The name of the servlet matches the servlet url in the web.xml, so that is not the issue. My servlet has the following code in it to receive the param as well. Under my doPost i have the following string statement. Can someone please help!

```
message /AcctAuthServlet
description The requested resource is not available

<li><a href="/AcctAuthServlet?action=logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Logout</a></li>

String action = request.getParameter("action");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a moron... remove the / from "/AcctAut...." to "AcctAuth...." and it works